# Execute a code when a callback disconnect from boost::signals2::signal

Tags: c++, boost, signals2

Short: Is there any way that I execute a code when a callback that connected using `connect` disconnected?

Long: I have a class with multiple callbacks that are expensive and I want to only generate callbacks for those that interested by user:

```
boost::signals2::connection bind_to_signal(signal_code code, signal_signature const& fn)
{
    start_callback(code);
    return signal_[code].connect(fn);
}
```

Now I want to execute `stop_callback` when all callbacks that bound to a signal disconnected.

Comment: Not only that you can't know when a slot disconnects, `signal` itself might not know that - until it attempts to invoke the slot.

Comment: ...by the way, your "long" description is unclear: if there are no connected slots, what is so expensive in "empty" signal invocation?

Comment: @IgorR. Invocation is not expensive, monitoring the original object that generate events is expensive! so I want to disable that monitoring.

Comment: I see. Then I'm afraid you've got only one way to go: provide your own `register`/`unregister` interface and fully hide `signal` as implementation detail (don't return `connection`, accept `function` as a callback but not `slot_type` - to prevent any possibility of disconnection other than through your `unregister` function).

Comment: @IgorR. thanks a lot, I am already doing this but I seek a way to accomplish with less code! and a cleaner design. If you want write it as an answer then I may accept it if no good answer received!